# Getting issue in rollout updates in GKE same steps working in on prem cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm Porting an micro service application to the kubernetes that was previously on on prem. I have follow the same steps as performed in the on prem for managing Deployment, Ingress, Service, PVS and all but when doing it on GKE getting errors while performing rollout updates on my deployments

ERROR: Cannot schedule pods: No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
[GKE issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyM3w.png)

I have followed the same steps that we generally do for rollout the updates on the Deployments but facing trouble to rollout the updates.